# "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified" despite /etc/odbc.ini having the DSN

Tags: pyodbc

Getting the `"[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"` despite `/etc/odbc.ini` having the DSN referenced in the connection string. Why would this be happening and what can be done?

Trying to set up `pyodbc` for connecting to MSSQLServer using the [docs (centos 7)](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7). Yet, when trying to actually connect to the database,

```
import pyodbc 

# setup db connection
server = 'myserver' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn_str = 'DSN=MyMSSQLServer;DATABASE='+database+'UID='+username+'PWD='+password+'MultipleActiveResultSets=True;'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

getting error `"[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"`, even though when running:

```
[mapr@mnode01 ~]$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[MyMSSQLServer] Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Description=My MS SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=<now using my sql server ip>
```

I can see that the DSN that I referenced in the python code is recorded in the `/etc/odbc.ini` file. Does anyone know what could be going on here? Thanks.

**Note**: I initially ran the pyodbc setup exactly as specified in the [docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7#prepare-a-temp-file-for-defining-the-dsn-to-your-database-server), but later re-did [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7#prepare-a-temp-file-for-defining-the-dsn-to-your-database-server) step to use the ip address of the sql server I wanted to connect to:

```
vi /home/user/odbcadd.txt

[MyMSSQLServer] Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Description = My MS SQL Server

Trace = No

Server = <my sql server ip>
```

and just re-ran the write to `odbc.ini`:

```
sudo odbcinst -i -s -f /home/user/odbcadd.txt -l
```

Comment: Check your odbc.ini file again. The `[MyMSSQLServer]` section needs to have a `Driver=` line (your original version didn't) and it must be on a separate line (not the same line as `[MyMSSQLServer]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution commented by user Gord Thompson solved my problem. The `~/odbcadd.txt` file that I was using to fill the `/etc/odbc.ini` file needed to have the *'Driver='* line on a separate line from the DSN to look like:

```
[mapr@mnode01 ~]$ cat /etc/odbc.ini 
[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Description=My MS SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=172.18.4.38
```